# How do i get mouse coordinates on screen ? And how ot format the coordinates with string.format?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to display the mouse coordinates X and Y on the form but even if I move the mouse all around the screen not only over the mouse area.

And second how to use string.format to display on a label the coordinates in real time of x and y.

I'm using this method to get the coordinates but i'm not sure if it's the coordinates of the screen and if it will display the mouse cursor position even if I move the mouse around all over the screen(monitor).

```
public static Point GetMousePositionWindowsForms()
        {
            System.Drawing.Point point = Control.MousePosition;
            return new Point(point.X, point.Y);
        }
```

And in the constructor i tried:

```
label1.Text = string.Format("X = " {GetMousePositionWindowsForms().X};
```

Not sure how to use the string.Format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the screen coordinates using this code:

```
var position = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position;
```

To display/format it, use something like this:

```
label1.Text = string.Format("X={0}, Y={1}", position.X, position.Y);
```

Comment: M4N what mouse move event should I use ? I tried Form1_MouseMove but that will take effect only inside the form1 area. I need it also to show in real time when moving the mouse around the screen area not only in the form area.

Comment: @ManuelSpechia: maybe use a timer and get the current cursor position periodically.

Comment: A timer would be a good way to go.  Easy to setup and use.  Otherwise you'd have to implement a low level mouse hook via WH_MOUSE_LL.  Not an easy task...

Comment: In Form1 load event i'm creating a windows forms timer interval set to 50ms start the timer. In the timer tick event I use the label1 with the string.Format very simple.